# How to provide read-only access to the storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I have created an Azure Storage Account in which multiple teams store the blobs/files. I want to provide read-only access to some team members and contributor access to some team members.

How to provide read-only access to the storage account?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to give them a SAS token.  See [Grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using shared access signatures (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview)

You can also [Authorize access to blobs using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Is there any alternative way (like using managed identity) instead of using the SAS token?

Comment: See updated answer.